# How to run iterations asynchronously in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, asynchronous, scripting

I have a few .csv files like below.

1. xyz0900@1#-1637746436.csv
2. xxx0900@1#-1637746436.csv
3. zzz0900@2#-1637746439.csv
4. yyy0900@1#-1637746436.csv
5. sss0900@2#-1637746439.csv

I have written a script to perform below tasks:

1. Get the large file based on the pattern which we have passed as a argument to the script.
2. Merge all other files which are having same pattern and create a new file
3. Remove duplicate header from new file.
4. Move new file to the destination based on the parameter passed as a argument.

> Example: I am passing "1637746436@home/dest1,1637746436@home/dest2" as
>   a second argument to the script. Below script will fetch the
>   pattern(1637746436). Get the bigger file and merge all other
>   files(having same pattern) with it. New file will be get created and same will be moved to the destination(home/dest1).

The below script will perform the pattern matching and execution sequentially.

**How to make 'for loop iteration' should be executed parallelly?** I mean pattern matching of "1637746436@home/dest1,1637746436@home/dest2" should be performed simultaneously(not one after another).

Please help on this.

```
$merge.sh /home/dummy/17 "1637746436@home/dest1,1637746439@home/dest2" 


 #!/bin/bash
 current=`pwd`
 source=$1
 destination=$2
 echo "$destination" | tr "," "\n" > $current/out.txt
 cat out.txt | cut -d "@" -f1 > $current/pattern.txt

 for var in `cat pattern.txt`
 do
 getBiggerfile=$(ls -Sl $source/*$var.csv | head -1)
 cd $source
 getFileName=$(echo $getBiggerfile | cut -d " " -f9-)
 newFileName=$(echo $getFileName | cut -d "@" -f1)
 cat *$var.csv >> $getFileName
 header=$(head -n 1 $getFileName)
(printf "%s\n" "$header";
 grep -vFxe "$header" $getFileName
 ) > $newFileName.csv
 rm -rf *$var.csv
 cd $current

 for var1 in `cat out.txt`
 do
 target=`echo $var1 | cut -d "@" -f2`
 id=$(echo $var1 | cut -c-10)
 if [ $id = $var ]
 then
 mv $newFileName.csv $target
 fi
 done
done
```

Comment: Potential cross site duplicate : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest would be to make the internals of the loop a function, and call the function inside the loop, putting it in the background (child processes), then wait for the background (child) processes to finish:

```
function do_the_thing(){
    source="$1"
    current="$2"
    var="$3"
    getBiggerfile=$(ls -Sl $source/*$var.csv | head -1)
    cd $source
    getFileName=$(echo $getBiggerfile | cut -d " " -f9-)
    newFileName=$(echo $getFileName | cut -d "@" -f1)
    cat *$var.csv >> $getFileName
    header=$(head -n 1 $getFileName)
    (printf "%s\n" "$header";
       grep -vFxe "$header" $getFileName
    ) > $newFileName.csv
    rm -rf *$var.csv
    cd $current

    for var1 in `cat out.txt`
    do
        target=`echo $var1 | cut -d "@" -f2`
        id=$(echo $var1 | cut -c-10)
        if [ $id = $var ]
        then
            mv $newFileName.csv $target
        fi
    done
}

for var in `cat pattern.txt`
do
    do_the_thing "$source" "$current" "$var" &
done

wait
```

Comment: @Jack-Thanks for your help. I tried above approach and it worked for me.